# Access http://myWindowsMachine on iPad Safari

Tags: javascript, iphone, html, ipad, web-applications

If I have a web app on my Windows machine (accessed via http://myWindowsMachine) and I have an iPad connected via the same Wifi outer as the Windows machine..

Can I access http://myWindowsMachine via my iPad Safari  ?

Please let me know how can I do that (even if it is via some app).

I also have a slight twist which I'll be asking later.

Comment: Do you have a web server setup on your Windows machine?

Comment: yes, that's correct..it's a weblogic server..

Comment: it's likely that your windows firewall is blocking port 80

Comment: Hi Matt...Sorry but I have not tried anything on the iPad yet..I do not know how exactly to access it..also what issues can come and ways to fix them ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, at a minimum you can find the IP address of your Windows machine and connect that way.  For example, http://192.168.0.1.

To find your Windows machine's IP address, go to a command prompt and type IPCONFIG.  It will display the computer's IP address.  Then use that from your iPad.

Comment: I am not sure if it is the same, but the way I access my web app on Windows for testing is just http://myMachineName ...Will the same not work for iPad?

Comment: I think that's an "it depends" type of answer, based on your router. "myMachineName" needs to be translated to an IP address some way, and that can be done via NETBIOS routing or perhaps DNS.  Your wifi-router's config screens may help you.